# What is difference between J2ME and J2ME Polish

Tags: j2mepolish

I did j2me program...now i need convert to j2me polish...how to do it..

Answer (score 3):

As Graham already stated J2ME Polish is not a new technology but rather a framework to simplify the development of J2ME applications across a broad range of devices. To use Polish you have to include their JARs into your buildpath, familiarize with their ANT build scripts and basically work through the documentation. It takes some time, but it's definitely worth it if you try to develop for different devices. Polish delivers a rich set of UI extensions, preprocessing of your source, localization and so much more. By taking advantage of their device database you can avoid known device bugs and build your application individually for each device.

Take the time to read the [documentation](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation.html).
Everything from installation to application build is explained there.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use J2Mepolish.It causes many problem.If you use j2mepolish then your application become working in a single type of device.Without using j2mepolish your application is working more than 1 type of devices.

If you want to use any framework means then you use "**LWUIT**".It is well suited to **J2ME** .

Both **J2ME and LWUIT** are **Sun's (Oracle)** product.

Comment: This is some what the point of J2ME Polish. I think you have not understood the point of the Polish framework. It allows you to target nearly just the amount of devices compared to J2ME. The point is to target each handset or group of handsets or handset capabilities, resolving the problems of the J2ME framework (e.g. bugs on certain phones, getting around device limitations) using various Polish framework techniques such as pre-processing,  statements, resource assemblying and device customization.